# Placing <input> tag inside the <form>

Tags: html, css, forms

I have the following form that I write:

```
<form class="form-margin cart-container">
    <div style="flex-direction: column">
        <app-cart-item class="cart-item" *ngFor="let pr of productRecordList" [productRecord]="pr"></app-cart-item>
    </div>

    <div class="cart-item-details">
        <textarea name="fullname" id="fullname" cols="35" rows="2" placeholder="(minimum 3 characters)">Full name</textarea>
        <textarea name="address" id="address" cols="35" rows="2" placeholder="(minimum 6 characters)">Address</textarea>
        <textarea name="creditcard" id="creditcard" cols="35" rows="2" placeholder="(16-digits number)">
Credit card number</textarea
        >
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Is it okay to have the `<input>` inside a `<div>` like the code provided or do I need to make sure that `<form>` is the direct parent like below?

```
<form>
   <div>
   ........................................
   ........................................
   </div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, this should be fine to do. Just keep the input elements inside the form to keep the form working.

Answer (score 3):

Structuring your form with divs is completely valid and not a bad practice at all. Although I wouldn't go to crazy with nesting, your form seems completely fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to use like that, but for the view of readability it's better to be under a parent form and refer that field with 'class' or 'id'.

Comment: Can you provide an example for that?

Comment: You can of course use anything in div, but leaving just the input of 'submit' can be very much useful for others who are referring the code. This will make sure to represent this IS the last input and it's the submit button of this form  . 

Refer this: This is a simple eg, hope it helps 
https://codepen.io/myofficialdev/pen/KKmOJaK